# Put .conan folder with cache to the current project folder

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, conan

Is there any way to create .conan folder in the root of the current project on building stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `CONAN_USER_HOME` environment variable to point to your current folder, that will put the Conan cache there. However this doesn't have many advantages, one of the reasons of having the cache separated is that it is way more efficient to have the packages installed in a common place, and they can be used in multiple projects. And given the structure of the cache, different versions or different configurations (shared/static, Debug/Release, etc) will not conflict, they can be installed simultaneously.

Conan 2.0 implements a `.conanrc` file that you can put in your project root and that allows defining the `CONAN_HOME` variable automatically.

Comment: i do not agree that isolating environment does not have any advantages. When you have different project sharing differents remotes settings, using all in the same .conan is really hard. Unfortunately conan 1.x does not provide a way to separate the config from the conan/data part that would benefit a lot from commonalization